# I have a function that calls connection to two of my collections in my database, and it stores it in two array but i cant access it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I made a connection to two collections and stored it in two arrays,  but I can't access it cause its asynchronous.

Also, I wanted to perform something like this 
SELECT roll FROM student

db.student.find({}, {roll:1, _id:0});

but implementing this doesn't work it just fetches everything from the collection.

I have tried using async/await but it didnt work.

I tried implementing the async (npm module) and used the async.series method but didnt work.

Using setTimeout to console.log logs the values but I need to perform some comparison, so it is not helpful.

```
    let collectionOneArr = [];
    let collectionTwoArr = [];

    let db = client.db('job');

    db.collection('one').find({}, {field:1, name: 0}).toArray((err, data) => {
        data.forEach(val => collectionOneArr.push(val))
    });

    db.collection('two').find({}).toArray((err,data) => {
        data.forEach(val => collectionTwoArr.push(val))
    });

   console.log(collectionOneArr) // returns []
   console.log(collectionTwoArr) // returns []

//    setTimeout(() => console.log(collectionTwoArr, collectionOneArr), 1000);

    client.close();    
});
```

Comment: this code is `node`? or `javascript`?

Comment: both node and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what the objects that are being stored in the database look like, but I will try to answer the question anyhow.

There are 2 issues that I can see.

1. You're not querying correctly
2. You need to work with javascript's asynchronous nature :)

**1. Incorrect mongo filtering**

You don't appear to be supplying the arguments to the `find` method in the correct order and aren't actually telling mongo to filter by anything.

The first argument to the [mongodb find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method is the filter object. This should properly filter:

```
db.collection('one').find({field:1, name: 0}).toArray((err, 
  data.forEach(val => collectionOneArr.push(val))
});
```

**2. Asynchronous issue**

We can use a `readyForCompute` flag for instance to make sure that we only run the `compute` method after both database queries have completed.
This is a very primitive solution and does not scale very well but is sufficient for performing only 2 queries.

```
let readyForCompute = false;
let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];

let db = client.db('job');

db.collection('one').find({name: "value_to_filter_name_field_by"}).toArray((err, data) => {
    arr1 = data;
    if (readyForCompute) compute();
    readyForCompute = true;
});

db.collection('two').find({}).toArray((err,data) => {
    arr2 = data;
    if (readyForCompute) compute();
    readyForCompute = true;
});

function compute() {
    client.close();
    console.log(arr1);
    console.log(arr2);
    // do your computation...
}
```

Comment: It works but the find({field:1, name: 0}) doesn't, after reading the documentation I tried find({field:true, name: false}), but it returns nothing

Comment: Progress is good.

I would imagine that the `name` field is what you're really trying to query by and it is a String value. If this is the case, you should have a filter object like `{name: "your_value_to_filter_by" }`